# How should I design a portable (one executable) WinForm GUI app and Windows Service?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to develop an application with VB.NET 4.7.2 Framework, using WinForms. The application must run like a service, that is, ran at Windows startup (after boot, before login). It's intended to run only on a local enviroment, and play some sound files while the local user hasn't logon yet.

My first aproach to this problem was developing a WinForm app that accepted command line args, so when it was executed without args, the GUI appeared to let the user customize some of the features of the program, and when it was executed with args, then no GUI is shown and music is played.
However, the method for detecting when login/logouts and other NT Session Events happened was by hooking a script onto the Windows Scheduler, which ended up being a bad idea, because half of the times, the program would lock up (as the Windows Scheduler would try to execute multiple times) or didn't even execute the program (because it didn't even fire up correctly the login event).

Now, I've considered remaking my code into two programs, a service that runs the code, and a GUI app that sets up the settings for the service program. My idea is to embed an executable inside the main GUI app executable, so it automatically extracts it to a folder in order to run the service program.

However, I can imagine this isn't a pretty clean solution; more so if it triggers by error an antivirus.

I would appreciate some kind of help to get this working on a much clean and safe way.

Note: The main goal of this question is to preserve the all-in-one executable format, if possible. If not, either design a way to run a WinForm app like a system service (run at Windows startup, before login), or two individual programs, one as a service and the other as the GUI program.

Comment: _The application must run like a service, that is, ran at Windows startup (after boot, before login). It's intended to run only on a local enviroment, and play some sound files while the local user hasn't logon yet...if it triggers by error an antivirus_: Sounds virus-like to me. What is the purpose of this program? What issue are you attempting to solve? Why would something like this be necessary?

Comment: Hmm, yeah...one executable for both the service and GUI...now there's a challenge. I've never tried creating a service our of the windows forms app. You're going to need a way to know if there is Human Interface Device or not, GUI or Service. Plus, getting the Windows Services database to allow you to create a entry for a service with a form.

I don't know,...I'm gonna go with no.

PS. You might have better luck with a console app and CLI, instead of GUI.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm seeking for advice, it just might be understood as some kind of virus (at least the way the app is deployed). The main focus of the app is to play music while on the logon screen, and when NT Logon Events are fired, like login, logout, user locked, windows start and windows shutdown. The issue I'm trying to fix is finding another way to deploy an application that works in background (might need to be ran as a service in order to run while no user has logged on yet), as my first aproach, the Windows Scheduler, has been proven not to work as intended.

Comment: My goals are the ones I have written on the post. I don't know where you got the 30 second loop, or why no one would want to have it anyway. I've taken inspiration from the system music played on the PlayStation 4 system, and I thought it was an interesting concept, and seeing how sparse customization can be in Windows, I didn't see why there should be a problem implementing this. Asking why nobody would want to have this program running can be the same question as why someone would want to have an animated background on the desktop, for example. And of course, it is not being helpful.

Comment: @PiporGames: I don't use an _animated background on the desktop_, Nonetheless, it's purpose is to prevent screen burn-in.

Comment: Interestingly enough, sometimes there are posts on SO to try to get help writing keyloggers, viruses, etc. The posters always seem to state that they are creating a game - attempting to conceal what they are really attempting to do - and always seem to have very few reputation points (ie: a new user).

Comment: Then what should I do? Upload the Windows Scheduler version to clarify? If I need to make an essay just to ask how to make a good design for something that needs to run while on the lockscreen, then what's the point? I've heard quite a lot of bad critiques about Stackoverflow, but being my reference site to guide myself on how to understand certain problems I ran into while coding, I thought maybe I could give it a chance. Months (or years, I can't remember) before I made my first post asking for help with blender and it was deleted because, well I don't even know anymore.

Comment: You may consider looking into how a screen saver works. For design questions, you may consider posting on a different Stack Exchange - perhaps [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).